# Dissable auto push remote notification ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am overriding both `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` and `ReceivedRemoteNotification` and leaving them empty in an attempt to prevent my remote notifications to push automatically, but it does not seem to help. Because every time I send a postman request for the notification, they still show up..  How can i prevent the notification from pushing until the app has met the necessary requirements (user is signed inn) ?

Comment: Send device token to your server when user logs in, else don't send it.

Comment: If have registered in app once, no matter what will receive notification. Unless unistalling app and reinstalling without registering. I think this should not be controlled in mobile. When push notification from server, server can specify which users need to send.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT so there is no way to intersect the notification before it is sent ? alternatively what function is called once the remote notification arrives ? (before the once mentioned above)

Comment: @Steinar Yeah ,if user allow the notification permission when running app first, the notification will arrive anyway. However you can set notification be silent mode, at least it seems look like no receiving notification.https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT if the notification is set to silent mode will it still be possible to manually send a notification using the `UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest` function ?

Comment: @Steinar Possible, you can .One is remote notification, and another is local notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app starts up, register or unregister, as soon as you know the app state

Unregister:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.UnregisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

Register:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
```

Comment: this is not quite what i need, i still want to be able to talk to my app..

Comment: @Steinar Update your question on exactly what your use-case looks like.